# How to check substring using regular expression in Nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I try to check some parameters in request. Here is my url:

```
http://localhost:8080/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=004C0000064F&
     STYLES=&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image%2fjpeg&CRS=EPSG%3a100000&DPI=96&
 MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3a96&
BBOX=1530569.52624839870259166%2c524135.21126760687911883%2c1531064.27656850102357566%2c524629.96158770937472582
```

I trying to get `REQUEST` parameter. Here is my  nginx 1.12.1 config:

```
server {
  listen      8080;
  server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;

  set $site_backend localhost:56297;

  proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  location /favicon.ico {
      error_page 403 404  =  @tomcat_static_mapping;
  }

  location ~* /wms {

      internal;
      add_header URI $request_uri;
      add_header X-debug-message1 "$request_uri" always;

      if ($request_uri ~* REQUEST=([^&]*)) {
          add_header X-debug-message2 "hi" always;
          set $requesttype $1;
      } 
  }
}
```

And in browser i got header:

```
X-debug-message1: /wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=004C0000064F&STYLES=&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image%2fjpeg&CRS=EPSG%3a100000&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3a96&BBOX=1530569.52624839870259166%2c524135.21126760687911883%2c1531064.27656850102357566%2c524629.96158770937472582
```

But not get `X-debug-message2` header. I check regular expression here https://rubular.com/ and it's found match and return `GetMap` as like i want.
What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not complete / matching in your post. I got `X-debug-message2: hi` *only* which does match to how nginx has to behave:

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level

For more intuitive outcome, use [Headers-More](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/nginx-module-headers-more.html) module.

```
 more_set_headers "URI: $request_uri";
 more_set_headers 'X-debug-message1: "$request_uri"';
 location ~* /wms {
     if ($request_uri ~* REQUEST=([^&]*)) {
         more_set_headers 'X-debug-message2: hi';
         set $requesttype $1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: When i removed `X-debug-message1` header i still do not have `X-debug-message2` header. So it's mean that code just to enter into my if check?

Comment: Yes. Are you actually requesting `/wms`? Things work as expected on my end.

Comment: Yeah i made typo in question text my url start with `http://localhost:8080/wms?...`.

Comment: I did realize that and adjusted my test, but things still worked consistently on my end.

Comment: i found whats was wrong. It is a `internal;` option. Has no clue why it's block config normal work, but when i'd removed this row all work fine.